# How to get Month-Year from a string of timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the Month & Year from a string of Timestamp.

**Attempted**:

```
 var x =  "2021-09-08T17:00:00.000Z"
 
 x.toLocaleString('en-us',{month:'short', year:'numeric'})
 
 console.log(x)`enter code here`
```

**Expected result**

```
x = "September 2021"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your code as follows

```js
var x = "2021-09-08T17:00:00.000Z"

var monthYear = new Date(x).toLocaleString('en-us', {
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
})

console.log(monthYear)
```

Comment: OP wants month as `September ` so could do as `month: "long"`

Comment: @HR01M8055 great pickup. I have edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this result using [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) method of [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object

```js
const x = "2021-09-08T17:00:00.000Z";

const monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];

const date = new Date(x);
const result = `${monthNames[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse it as a date object.

```js
 const x =  "2021-09-08T17:00:00.000Z"
 const y = new Date(x)
```

then you can use the date methods.

```js
console.log(y.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long", year: "numeric" }));
```

outputs: `September 2021`